# How to run Eclipse java JUnit test suite from command line? (windows)

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I've been developing a test suite for a provided "solution.jar" file in Eclipse for an assignment. I have a test suite which I can run in eclipse no problem, but the assignment requires that I run it from the command line, but I've no idea how to do this.

I've tried:

```
java -cp .;/usr/share/java/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore AllTests
```

but it just said Error: could not load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Which version JAR for Junit?  Look in the JAR for the main class.

Answer (score -1):

you can use maven build and then from command prompt fire this command

```
mvn test
```

It will run test case associated with your project.

Comment: This assumes OP uses Maven.